# Adding drawableEnd to a SwitchCompat in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-switch, switchcompat

I am working on an Android app in which I want to have a `SwitchCompat` with a `drawable` shown between the switch text and the switch toggle view as shown below.

[image: Intended switch]

For that, I thought `android:drawableEnd` would work fine, but contrary to my expectations, it places the `drawable` to the end of the switch toggle as shown below.

[image: Actual switch]

Is there any way I can achieve this effect except for showing the drawable between a separate `TextView` for the text and a separate `SwitchCompat` for the toggle?

Comment: you could use textview, and a imageview and a switchcompact in a linearlayout. drawableEnd works as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible workaround. Thanks!

Comment: or you would need to extend a compound button yourself and style them and draw the components you need which is a lot of work. I tried extending switchcompact but not all api's are exposed public so you would have to draw a custom view yourself by measuring and doing all calculations yourself.

Comment: Yeah exactly. This is a lot of extra work for something that is not as demanding. Could you please write out all this into an answer so that I can accept it and close this loop?